# ng-file-upload Amazon s3 REST API Authorization error

Tags: php, angularjs, file-upload, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

OK... I have been on this for a while now and I'm not getting anywhere. No matter what I try, I continue to get back the same error message from Amazon.

```
<Error>
  <Code>InvalidArgument</Code>
  <Message>Unsupported Authorization Type</Message>
  <ArgumentName>Authorization</ArgumentName>
  <ArgumentValue>Basic U1Q6</ArgumentValue>
  <RequestId>80B90936C37C0CEE</RequestId>
  <HostId>NphuQmN38ri6LvRAlpec8dSC2YwqOKD15ozInX7UmRPhFPZsGmFIghziNfzB/Y7o</HostId>
</Error>
```

I am using ng-file-upload (https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload) to upload to S3. I have followed the documentation and have used the demo installation to successfully upload a file to my bucket so I know my AWS Key and Secret Key are correct.

My controller is as follows:

```
AWSs3 = {
        key:  'AWS-KEY-HERE',
        filename: file[0].name,
        fileSize: file[0].size,
        fileType: file[0].type,
        bucket: 'manual-attachments',
        acl: 'public-read',
        timestamp: timestamp
    }

$http({
        method: "post",
        url: "../api/manuals/s3",
        data: AWSs3
    }).success(function(data, status, headers, config){                                     
        file.upload = $upload.upload({
        url : 'https://bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/',
        method : 'POST',
        fields : {
                key: file[0].name,
                acl: AWSs3.acl,
                AWSAccessKeyId: AWSs3.key,
                policy: data.policy,
                signature: data.signature,
                "Content-Type"  : file.type === null || file.type === '' ? 'application/octet-stream' : file.type,
                filename: file[0].name
                },
                file : file,
            });

            file.upload.then(function(response) {
                $timeout(function() {
                    file.result = response.data;
                });
            }, function(response) {
                if (response.status > 0)
                    $scope.errorMsg = response.status + ': ' + response.data;
            });

            file.upload.progress(function(evt) {
                file.progress = Math.min(100, parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total));
                });

    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config){
        $log.info('{Error: '+data+'}');
        return false;
    });
```

Now the PHP for generating the policy and signature is as follows:

```
class S3 {
    public static $AWS_ACCESS_KEY           = "AWS-KEY";
    public static $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY    = "AWS-SECRET-KEY";

    public static function get_policy_and_signature( array $data )
    {
       $policy = self::get_policy_doc( $data );
       $signature = self::get_signature( $policy );

       if ( strpos($signature, '+') !== FALSE )
       {
           $data['timestamp'] = intval(@$data['timestamp']) + 1;
           return self::get_policy_and_signature( $data );
       }

       return '{"policy": "'.$policy.'", "signature":"'.$signature.'"}';
    }

    public static function get_policy_doc(array $data)
    {
       $now = strtotime(date("Y-m-d\TG:i:s"));
       $expire = date('Y-m-d\TG:i:s\Z', strtotime('+ 10 minutes', $now));

      return base64_encode(
           '{'.
               '"expiration": "'.$expire.'",'.
               '"conditions": '.
               '['.
                   '{"bucket": "'.$data['bucket'].'"},'.
                   '["starts-with", "$key", ""],'.
                   '{"acl": "public-read"},'.
                   '{"success_action_status": "201"},'.
                   '["starts-with", "$Content-Type", ""],'.
                   '["starts-with", "$filename", ""],'.
                   '["content-length-range",0,5242880]'.
               ']'.
           '}'
       );
    }

    public static function get_signature( $policy_doc ) {
       return base64_encode(hash_hmac(
           'sha1', $policy_doc, self::$AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, true
       ));
    }
}
```

The http headers show "Authorization:Basic U1Q6" which is obviously the issue. Any assistance with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a complete idiot! The header was being created by my own login/authorisation script.

I completely forgot! Once I fixed that I had no issues.